# Need help in Symbology for ArcGIS JS API 3.2/3.3

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology, arcgis-desktop

I am displaying various symbols in my application and initially all are displaying at once (looks like bulky) so how do I set symbol levels in ArcGIS so that according to zoom level symbol size will increase or it will auto-fit according to resolution. Please check the screenshot for various levels.

[image: Level 1]

[image: Level 2]

[image: Level 3]

I am researching on my side and [ArcGIS help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000039000000). (I think visible scale range will work but I am not sure and total layers are five so should I set same levels for all layers?

**Update :**

I can not change the default extent (because that layers data is coming dynamically (We have data across the world so setting to specific extent is not possible))

Software : ArcGIS Server/Desktop 10.1 , ArcGIS JSAPI 32./3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symbology rendering, scaling, and labeling is defined within your map document.  To define layer scales:

1. Right click each layer in the Table of Contents and select Properties
2. Select the General tab and define min and max scale for each layer
3. Save your map document, and then re-publish your service